# Unable to connect to postgres using docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a very simple `docker-compose.yml` file which currently is only to set up a `posgresql` database, but I can't connect to it once it is running. Instead I get this error:

```
2022-10-10 11:19:41.820 UTC [43] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2022-10-10 11:19:41.820 UTC [43] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1) running in data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"?
```

The docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - /pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

When I try to connect to the running container I use:

```
docker exec -it -u postgres 31f122d6a413 postgres
```

The logs from the container are:

```
Recreating test-docker-proj ... 
WARNING: Service "db" is using volume "/var/lib/postgresql/data" from the previous container. Host mapping "/pgdata" has no effect. 
Recreating test-docker-proj ... done
Attaching to test-docker-proj
db_1  | 
db_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1  | 
db_1  | 2022-10-10 11:05:02.349 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 on aarch64-unknown-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 11.2.1 20220219, 64-bit
db_1  | 2022-10-10 11:05:02.349 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1  | 2022-10-10 11:05:02.349 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1  | 2022-10-10 11:05:02.352 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1  | 2022-10-10 11:05:02.356 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-10-10 10:47:01 UTC
db_1  | 2022-10-10 11:05:02.361 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

It seems that postgres/docker is persisting user login details from previous containers or something? I am at a bit of a loss anyway, so any guidance would be appreciated.

I am using:
Mac Monterey M1
docker-compose version 1.29.2

Probably worth adding that I can connect to the container using `/bin/sh` rather than `postgres`

Comment: You are pointing the container at an existing directory (`/pgdata`), which apparently contains an existing database. If you don't want to use the credentials stored in that database, then delete the contents of `/pgdata` before you start your container.

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense. I keep getting this error now, and cant really figure out why. I guess as part of the database initiation it creates user permissions, and that just isnt working? Here is the error:  `"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted. The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.`

Comment: Are you using a locally built `postgres` image or the official postgres image?

Comment: the official one from here https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres